# custom reset password django

Tags: django, passwords, reset

can anybody lead to how to implement custom reset password in Django
I wanna implement it to able to reset the password with the username and email
I searched a lot but I didn't find a good one

thanks a lot

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far, rather than asking for the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a custom method on the user, called `user.set_password()` which you can use to reset the password of any user. So it really depends on which route you want to go with this.

We've implemented a password reset magic link, which in essence is a view that checks the link and then changes the password of the request.user with this method.

Comment: yes, thanks for answering.. but something that I need is custom forget password.. I am so sorry for my mistake...

Comment: What do you mean then with custom forget password? A custom view or something?

Comment: it means a reset password without auth. view that is a built-in function in django...it can reset password with username maybe